# How can I set dynamic value inside the vue href link?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to set a dynamic value in the URL in href. I am using Vue.js

```
 <a
          href="https://example.com/glasses/guide-for-uploading"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Check it here
        </a>
```

So in the middle of URL I need to replace glasses with productName. How can be it done correctly in this link? I am not sure if simple data binding is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can using data binding.

```
<a
          :href="`https://example.com/glasses/${productName}`"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Check it here
        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either bind href like:

```
:href="'https://example.com/glasses/${productName}'"
```

Or you can achieve the same result using string:

```
Let link = document.getElemntById("linkId")
Let address = "https://example.com/glasses/" + this.productName

link.href = address
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use
:href="`!${url}!`"
it works for me replace `!` with back Quote ( ` ) cold not display because it use highlights the inner part in this editor